# vb.net database application does not work on user machine if database is password protected

Tags: vb.net, password-protection, jet

In vb.net I am using password protected database with following connection string

connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\vai\vaiDB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=secret;"

Database access works fine on the development machine.

But when i copy the exe and the database file on the user machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening an Access database (.MDB) creates a temporary .LDB file in the same directory. Does the user logged in to the target PC have write permissions to directory C:\vai\?

Comment: yes the user has the permission to create the temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

If your DB is in the right location, what error message are you getting?

Comment: I used try and catch but using it i could not get the error taking place. How to catch the errors through code so that errors can be caught when exe is run?